# How to put ckeditor 5 toolbar at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using the Classic Distribution of Ckeditor 5.
Currently I am using this code to set up my ckeditor WYSIWYG.

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#cdc_content' ),{
        language: 'fr',
        toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', '|', 'undo', 'redo'],
          toolbarLocation: 'bottom',
     })
     .catch( error => 
   {
      console.error( error );
   }
      );
```

```html
<textarea name="cdc_content" id="cdc_content"></textarea>
```

I use `toolbarLocation: 'bottom'` to put my toolbar at the bottom but it does not work.

If anyone has a solution to remedy that it will help me.

Thank you in advance !